# EC2上で、sudo nodeコマンドが動作しない

Tags: aws, node.js, amazon-ec2, sudo

**質問**
EC2上で80番ポートのhttpサーバーをNode.jsで立てることになり、nodeを管理者権限で実行する必要があります。
そこで、下記のようにsudo nodeを実行すると、

```
[ec2-user@(ip-adress)~]$sudo node app.js
sudo: node: コマンドが見つかりません
```

という結果になります。
nodeコマンドでは動作するにも関わらず、sudo nodeでは上手く動作しません。
動作しない原因は何でしょうか？
また、どうすれば管理者権限でnodeを実行できるのでしょうか？

以下、詳細になります。

**環境**
Node v13.12.0

**試したこと**
[リンク](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976658/on-ec2-sudo-node-command-not-found-but-node-without-sudo-is-ok)を参考に

```
[ec2-user@(ip-adress) ~]$ sudo ln -s /root/.nvm/v13.12.0/bin/node/usr/bin/node
[ec2-user@(ip-adress) ~]$ sudo ln -s /root/.nvm/v13.12.0/lib/node /usr/lib/node
[ec2-user@(ip-adress) ~]$ sudo ln -s /root/.nvm/v13.12.0/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
[ec2-user@(ip-adress) ~]$ sudo ln -s /root/.nvm/v13.12.0/bin/node-waf /usr/bin/node-waf
```

コマンドを入力しましたが同様のエラーになります

**パス**
nodeのパスとcurrentパスは以下の通りです

```
[ec2-user@(ip-adress) ~]$ whereis node
node: /usr/lib/node /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/bin/node
[ec2-user@(ip-adress) ~]$ echo $PATH
/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
```

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `sudo ln -s /root/.nvm/v13.12.0/bin/node/usr/bin/node` が書き写し時の間違いでなければ、必要なスペースが抜けています。本来なら `sudo ln -s /root/.nvm/v13.12.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node` とする必要があるはず。 / "コマンドが見つからない" なので、`PATH` の確認等も sudo 後の root 権限の環境で行う必要があります。

Comment: 関連質問: [sudoで$PATHを引き継ぎつつsbinなどをPATHに加えるには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18862/) [シェルスクリプトをsudoしても環境変数を引き継ぎたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/16487/)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。第一引数のnodeまでのパスを間違えていたのが原因でした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決したようなので回答として投稿しておきます。

---

実行したコマンドのうち、以下の行でスペースが抜けているのが原因だと思います。
(ホームディレクトリ直下にシンボリックリンクが作成されてしまっているはず)

```
$ sudo ln -s /root/.nvm/v13.12.0/bin/node/usr/bin/node
```

正しくは以下になります。

```
$ sudo ln -s /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```